# overflow-x: hidden !important issue

Tags: html, css, overflow

"overflow-x: hidden !important;" was causing an issue where the browsers side bar was getting cut off (overlapped). Removing this fixed that error, however, one and only one of the pages Header is running off the screen when viewing in mobile. Here is the code, changing the position from fixed to absolute fixes the issue but i need the header to be fixed. In Desktop view, everything is fine. only in mobile and only on one page. Its strange. Here is the code responsible for the size of the screen i am having issues with.

```
@media screen and (min-width: 321px) and (max-width: 759px){
.navbar-mj{
   position: fixed;
   width: 100%;
   top: 0px;
   z-index: 89;
   background-color:#6782af;
   margin-bottom: 0;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a little difficult to tell what your issue is without seeing a more complete example but what if you remove the `width: 100%` and then add `right: 0` and `left: 0`?

Answer (score 0):

try lower the (max-width: 500px); 
it may help you instead of overflow the screen of the mobile view.
thanks

Comment: also try to remove the **width:100%**

Comment: yes this one worked, size was 360px i don't know why i didn't think of this earlier, the only problem is, having 360px is fine at lower pixel size screens but when it gets to higher ones. its an issue, i guess i have to create another media query?

Comment: meaning, setting set pixel sizes would not be dynamic on different screen resolutions.